# bika.lims-3.0rc2.3-py2.7.egg ImportError: could not import gobject

Tags: plone

I am trying to start Plone after installing Bika LIMS but am getting the following error:

`ImportError: could not import gobject (error was: ImportError('When using gi.repository you must not import static modules like "gobject". Please change all occurrences of "import gobject" to "from gi.repository import GObject".',))`

Here is a link to Pastebin: http://pastebin.com/embed_iframe.php?i=HkJgRZmJ

Answer (score 1):

This does not seem to be a Plone issue, but to gi Python package (whatever it is).

```
   "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
```

I suggest you contact directly to BIKA authors to resolve the issue with them.